# Create new Data frame from an existing one in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I created this dataframe with pySpark from txt file that includes searches queries and user ID.

```
`spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
    .option("delimiter", "\t") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/my_data.txt")
    
df.select("AnonID","Query").show()`
```

And it look like that:

```
+------+--------------------+
|AnonID|               Query|
+------+--------------------+
|   142|      rentdirect.com|
|   142|www.prescriptionf...|
|   142|          staple.com|
|   142|          staple.com|
|   142|www.newyorklawyer...|
|   142|www.newyorklawyer...|
|   142|     westchester.gov|
|   142|       space.comhttp|
|   142|                dfdf|
|   142|                dfdf|
|   142|         vaniqa.comh|
|   142| www.collegeucla.edu|
|   142|          www.elaorg|
|   142|        207 ad2d 530|
|   142|        207 ad2d 530|
|   142|   broadway.vera.org|
|   142|   broadway.vera.org|
|   142|            vera.org|
|   142|   broadway.vera.org|
|   142|    frankmellace.com|
|   142|         ucs.ljx.com|
|   142|   attornyleslie.com|
|   142|merit release app...|
|   142| www.bonsai.wbff.org|
|   142|         loislaw.com|
|   142|           rapny.com|
|   142|      whitepages.com|
|   217|             lottery|
|   217|             lottery|
|   217|      ameriprise.com|
|   217|             susheme|
|   217|          united.com|
|   217|          mizuno.com|
|   217|p; .; p;' p; ' ;'...|
|   217|p; .; p;' p; ' ;'...|
|   217|asiansexygoddess.com|
|   217|            buddylis|
|   217|bestasiancompany.com|
|   217|             lottery|
|   217|             lottery|
|   217|             ask.com|
|   217|         weather.com|
|   217|      wellsfargo.com|
|   217|www.tabiecummings...|
|   217|     wanttickets.com|
|   217|           yahoo.com|
|   217|                   -|
|   217|    www.ngo-quen.org|
|   217|                   -|
|   217|             vietnam|
+------+--------------------+
```

What I want to do is that each user ID will be a row and each query will be in a column.

```
+------+------------+---------
|ID |   1   |   2   |    3     .......
+------+------------+---------
|142| query1|query2| query3
|217| query1|query2| query3
|993| query1|query2| query3
|1268| query1|query2| query3
|1326| query1|query2| query3
  .
  .        
  .
```

I tried to switch between rows and columns with the help of a search I did on Google, but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the dataframe by `AnonID`, and then pivot the `Query` column to create new columns for each unique query:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.groupBy("AnonID").pivot("Query").agg(F.first("Query"))
```

If you have a lot of distinct values try

```
df = df.groupBy("AnonID").agg(F.collect_list("Query").alias("Queries"))
```

You can then rename the columns to 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
df = df.selectExpr("AnonID", *[f"`{i+1}` as `{i+1}`" for i in range(len(df.columns)-1)])
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried and I got this error:

"AnalysisException:  The pivot column Query has more than 10000 distinct values, this could indicate an error. If this was intended, set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues to at least the number of distinct values of the pivot column."

Comment: Just now I saw your edit..what is the big "F"? which package did you use?

Comment: Add this: `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`